# MomentJS: Date parsing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to parse a date coming from database to display on the `HTML`

I am using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) to help me with this task.

However, somewhere I am not doing it right so it is giving me incorrect results. Can some one please help

Here is the code

```
var d = 'Wed, 07 Aug 2013 00:00:00 -0000';
console.log('date from server: ' + d);
console.log('valid date? ', moment(d).isValid());

var newd = moment.utc(d);
console.log('year after parsing:', newd.year());
console.log('month after parsing:', newd.month());
console.log('day after parsing:', newd.day());
```

results in

```
date from server: Wed, 07 Aug 2013 00:00:00 -0000
valid date?  true
year after parsing: 2013
month after parsing: 7
day after parsing: 3
```

I have a small demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/66TB5RdI6w7MDYfp9qMj?p=preview)

**needed?**
I want to display the date as `August 8, 2013` on the web page

Comment: You're probably looking for `newd.format('MMMM D, YYYY')`. Have you read the moment.js documentation? `.day()` returns *day of the week*. `.month()` is *zero-based*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on DCoder's comment,

It seems that date was parsing correctly, but I needed to do formatting of the date

```
console.log(newd.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
```

produced

```
Aug 7, 2013
```

and this is what I needed

Thank you DCoder!